# SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 10g and sql developer for writing queries.

I have a user `ESTRADM` and it has some tables and some Materialized Views . I am trying to insert a row into an table `MTEP_THREEDS_CARD_MASTER` and its respective Materialized view is `MTEP_THREEDS_CARD_MASTER` (both table and view has same name).

Now when I execute query

```
insert into ESTRADM.MTEP_THREEDS_CARD_MASTER values (col1,col2,..);
```

it gives me an error:

> Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view
>   01732. 00000 -  "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

My Materialized view has QUERY REWRITE DISABLED.

I didn't get this why it is trying to insert into the view why it is not writing into the table ?
How can i insert a row into the table ?

Comment: Table and view are in same schema? In same schema a table and view cannot have the same name.

Comment: actually i have imported schema from a .dmp it has imported materialized views and tables, the table and materialzed view has same name.

Comment: Actually i am not in administrator privileges so i cannot rename it.

Comment: DBA can rename or request to provide necessary privileges to carry out the tasks.

Comment: Can it be a case that as i am not in administrator i am not able to change the table because i am also not able to access sqlplus from normal user and i installed oracle 10g and sql developer as admin user

Comment: If you can create a table then do so and try inserting rows, otherwise do as what been mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Tables and MV's almost always have the same name -- it's the default naming when creating an MV. So not so surprising really. Tables and materialized views are in different namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Only a subset of materialised views can be directly modified, and in order to be so they must adhere to strist rules laid out in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14226/repmview.htm

If your MV definition meets these restrictions and is still not modifiable then post the definition of the MV and the complete definitions, including constraints, of all of the tables that it references.